# I've lost my audio strip. Where did it go?

Tags: audio

sorry about this, I'm a bit of a noob.

I'm just starting out and I'm running a few lip sync tests with blender studio's RAIN rig.

So, I imported an audio track and have realised it would be much easier to work with it, if I could see the wav form... So, I went to select it to activate the WAV form, but I can't find the audio source-strip anywhere in the sequencer, just thousands of empty tracks... I'm sure there's a simple fix, but I can't find anything online.

Any help would be appreciated[image]

Comment: is it not at the bottom, on the first tracks? maybe select all (A) and press the "." key of the numpad

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for being so stoopid!

Answer (score 0):

Look on the left of the editor window, you've scrolled upwards a lot, so use the handle on the right to scroll down, or select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press the <kbd>.</kbd> of the numpad keys, which will center the selection.